# Какие технологии нужны, чтобы использовать switch в android

Tags: java, android, mobile-development, android-switch

Хочу сделать активити для настройки уведомления. Что вообще нужно использовать при работе со свитчем? условно хочу, чтобы при активированном свитче уведомления приходили, а когда свитч в положении off, уведомления не приходили.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос поставлен довольно странно на мой субъективный взгляд. Обратимся к [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch):

> Переключатель - это виджет с двумя состояниями, который может выбирать
>   между двумя вариантами. Пользователь может перетаскивать «большой
>   палец» назад и вперед, чтобы выбрать выбранную опцию, или просто
>   нажать, чтобы переключиться, как если бы это был флажок. Свойство `text`
>   управляет текстом, отображаемым в метке для переключателя, тогда как
>   текст `off` и on управляет текстом на большом пальце. Точно так же
>   `textAppearance` и связанные методы `setTypeface()` управляют гарнитурой и
>   стилем текста метки, тогда как методы switchTextAppearance и связанные
>   с ним `setSwitchTypeface()` управляют таковыми для большого пальца.

вот еще например можно встретить такое [определение](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/switch.php):

> Switch - ещё один вид переключателей, который появился в Android 4.0
>   (API 14). Находится в разделах Commons и Buttons. Фактически, это
>   замена немного устаревшего ToggleButton. В новых проектах лучше
>   использовать Switch.

Вот пример работы с виджетом. Для начала добавляем в xml:

```
<Switch
android:id="@+id/monitored_switch"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="32dip"
android:text="Переключатель с собственным текстом"
android:textOff="Выкл"
android:textOn="Вкл" />
```

Добавляем слушатель:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Switch switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.monitored_switch);
        if (switch != null) {
            switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Отслеживание переключения: " + (isChecked ? "on" : "off"),
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

На этом технологии заканчиваются. Знаний по технологиям почти не нужно, есть только главная технология которую мы все должны знать в совершенстве - вот [она](https://www.google.ru/). Эта на первый взгляд простая технология открывает путь к многим секретам и плюшкам :)

Теперь по поводу сохранения состояния. Я бы советовал использовать [sharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) для этих целей. Таким образом вы сможете программно сохранить в памяти телефона значение отвечающее какой-то функции. При включении switch делаем так в слушателе нажатий на виджет:

```
SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
mSettings.edit().putBoolean("switch_state, isChecked).apply();
```

переменная `isChecked` находится здесь:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
```

Дальше при запуске приложения мы проверяем есть ли что-то в памяти и устанавливаем значение в виджете:

```
SharedPreferences mSettings= getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Switch yourSwitch= (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
yourSwitch.setChecked(mSettings.getBoolean("switch_state", false));
```

А уже что делать при том или ином состоянии виджета вам решать :)

P.S. Не знаю как правильно перевести thumb из документации :( Переводится как палец, может стоит как-то изменить перевод, например - управляющий элемент, или просто переключатель. Буду рад любым идеям.

Comment: я это всё читал и собственно знал) мне интересно было, условно, сохранять состоянии свитча и чтобы он влиял на работу логики приложения. Хотя согласен, глупый вопрос)

Comment: @Денис, обновил ответ